# Mysql Multiple ANDS

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have three tables **persons**, **jobs**, **jobs_persons**

One person can have **multiple** jobs.

**Person 1** is Technical Support AND Manager

**Person 2** is Technical Support

**Person 3** Is Manager

**Job 1** Technical Support

**Job 2** Manager

I need to find a query give me the result for the person who currently is Technical Support AND Manager

The answer would be only Person 1

```
SELECT persons.*
FROM persons INNER JOIN jobs_persons ON persons.id = jobs_persons.person_id
INNER JOIN jobs ON jobs.id = jobs_persons.job_id
WHERE job.id IN (1,2)
```

**Returns 3 rows**

```
SELECT persons.*
FROM persons INNER JOIN jobs_persons ON persons.id = jobs_persons.person_id
INNER JOIN jobs ON jobs.id = jobs_persons.job_id
WHERE job.id = 1 AND job.id = 2
```

**Returns 0 rows.**

I'm currently working on Ruby on Rails.
Somebody can help?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you dead-set on using raw SQL? Why not use the functionality built in to the framework?

Comment: IN means "is equal to one OR more value in the list" not "is equal to all the values in the list. What is the scheme in your database for storing each person's job?

Comment: Dave Newton - if you have the framework solution ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use an `OR` operator. Using `job.id = 1 AND job.id = 2` will only return elements where id equals 1 and at the same time 2. No element can do that. You want elemets where th id is 1 or where the id is 2.

to make it more obvious:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE lastname = 'Smith' AND firstname = 'James';
```

when executing this you obviously don't want everybody who is called Smith or James. ;-)

EDIT:

Misread the question. what you need is a second join to join the jobs table two times in and join them with the different jobs. It is a bit hard as you didn't show the schema, but this might work:

```
SELECT persons.*
FROM persons
INNER JOIN jobs_persons jp1 ON persons.id = jp1.person_id
INNER JOIN jobs_persons jp2 ON persons.id = jp2.person_id
INNER JOIN jobs j1 ON j1.id = jp1.job_id 
INNER JOIN jobs j2 ON j2.id = jp2.job_id
WHERE j1.id = 1 AND j2.id = 2
```

Comment: From the question: "I need to find a query give me the result for the person who currently is Technical Support AND Manager"

Comment: But in this case will returns the 3 rows two. The point is really to fetch 1 row. The person have the 2 jobs. Thank you.

Comment: ah sorry, misread it, that's a bit more complicated, give me a sec :-)

Comment: Yeah, this could be a good answer but, imagine i want to find 3 diferent jobs

Comment: Ok, this one on performance it's very good. but to write is more dificult. If we want something dynamically it's a little bit harder.

Answer (score 2):

Try this to get all the person who has got a job of 1 AND 2 in your associative entity table. No need to hit the job table.

```
SELECT p.*
FROM persons p
WHERE id in (
   SELECT person_id FROM jobs_persons 
   WHERE job_id IN (1,2)
   GROUP BY person_id 
   HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
);
```

With your recent comments, it seems you're having performance problems. That's really outside of the scope of this question and answer.

You need to make sure your indexes are in place on the appropriate columns:

- jobs_person.job_id
- persons.id

Comment: Problem: When we have 200 rows to fetch it's coool but... when you have 20K Lines of persons and the query takes 60s to be performed. is not that so good. :S :(

Comment: Sorry but this one, is very good so, but for performance, downside it's best. Even that, i appreciate so much your help. I had this runnig, but when the client came with his database with 20K lines only for test, for production will be three times more. i had to reconsider.

Comment: Your indexes are the performance problem. Doesn't matter if you issue an EXPLAIN statement, you need to ensure that you have your indexes in good shape [rebuild them](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/rebuilding-tables.html) and make sure they're on the appropriate columns.

Comment: I have index on:
jobs_persons job_id, person_id
the jobs: id is Primary key